# Do All nth Roots Of Complex Numbers Only Yield Complex Solutions, That Is, No Purely Real Solutions?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, radicals

For Example, if i had the nth root of (a+ib), are its solutions always in the form of (x + iy) such that y can't be zero [in other words, the nth root of a complex number always yields another complex number, that is, never any purely real numbers].

Comment: Think about it: If $w = z^{1/n}$ is purely real, then $z=w^n$ is also purely real.

Answer (score 1):

There are complex numbers, where the n.th root of this number is allways purely real like 0.
Don't forget that purely real numbers are complex numbers too!
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{R} &\in \mathbb{C}\\
\mathbb{R} &\in \left\{a + b \cdot \mathrm{i} ~ \mid ~ a, ~b \in \mathbb{R} \land i^{2} = -1 \right\}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Aka if we found a purely real number a with
$$ \sqrt[n]{a} \in \mathbb{R} $$
for every n, we would find a complex number z with
$$ \sqrt[n]{z_{z \in \mathbb{C}}} \in \mathbb{R} $$
for every n too.

A number for which this applies is zero.
The n.th root of Zero (a complex Number) is allways Zero (if n is real and bigger then 0) (a purely real number).
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{z_{z \in \mathbb{C}}} \in \mathbb{R}\\
\sqrt[n]{0} = 0 \in \mathbb{R}\\
\sqrt[1010,2233]{0} = 0 \in \mathbb{R}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: "Don't forget that purely real numbers are complex numbers too!" People like to fight about this language convention, but I agree with you here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to ask is:

> If $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$, can $z^{\frac{1}{n}} \in \mathbb{R}$ for $n \in \{1,2,3,...\}$?

Suppose that this is true, then let $\omega = z^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$. We know any complex number can be written as $r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ for some constant $r \in \mathbb{R}$; thus, $z = \omega^{n}=r^{n}(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^{n}$. Applying De Moivre's formula will give us $z = r^{n}(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))$. Therefore, it is evident that if $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, then $z \in \mathbb{R}$ (because $\sin(n\theta)$ must be $0$). This contradicts our initial assumption. So the answer to the revised question is no, it cannot.